# Date calculations give different results in different environments

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

This query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT 0 n
         UNION ALL
         SELECT n + 1 FROM cte WHERE n < 20)
SELECT n, ('2020-04-13 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin'::timestamptz - make_interval(days => n)) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'
FROM cte
ORDER BY n
```

On my machine it gives this result:

[image: screenshot]

Note that the time switches from 00:00 to 23:00 on the day of the DST switch.

On dbfiddle.uk ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=82b71ef3bd6b100e44e21e8e5da2e5c9)) the query gives this result:

[image: screenshot]

Note that it shows `00:00` for all days, there is no change on the day of the DST switch.

And then on sqlfiddle.com ([Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/73971)) the result is:

[image: screenshot]

Here we have the switch again, but something else is strange here: The time zone of the result is given as `Z` (UTC) even though everything before was in time zone `Europe/Berlin`.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com is not running a pure community PostgreSQL.  It is their own compilation and has been whacked around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

sqlfiddle.com might interpret returned timestamps as having a timezone.

But PostgreSQL does not store a timezone along with a timestamp.
`timestamp with timezone` fields are internally stored in UTC: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

A timezone is not returned in this query either.

So this behavior of sqlfiddle.com is misleading.